# CefSharp Drag Form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, drag, cefsharp

I have a problem. I want to make the Form draggable not from the border, how it's made with the black bar on the top, but using an html element with attribute "-webkit-app-region: drag".

I tried, but I can't make it.
How can I make it to work?

[image]